# Is there a way to implement a list using only stacks?

Tags: algorithm

I wonder if there is a way to implement a list using only stacks. Is there?

Answer (score 2):

You can make a (inefficient) list using two stacks. When you need to insert or retrieve an item, just move items from one stack to the other until you get the right index.

Here’s an example in JavaScript:

```
function List() {
    this.stack1 = [];
    this.stack2 = [];

    Object.defineProperty(this, 'length', {
        get: function() { return this.stack1.length + this.stack2.length; }
    });
}

List.prototype.item = function(index) {
    if(index < this.stack1.length) {
        while(index < this.stack1.length - 1) {
            this.stack2.push(this.stack1.pop());
        }

        return this.stack1[this.stack1.length - 1];
    }

    while(index > this.stack1.length) {
        this.stack1.push(this.stack2.pop());
    }

    return this.stack2[this.stack2.length - 1];
};

List.prototype.insert = function(item, index) {
    this.item(index - 1);
    this.stack1.push(item);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

by list, do you mean queue?becaue I can't see any connection between stack and list...

if so,you can use two stacks: s1 san s2 , imagine they are bottom to bottom. s1 is the head of a list and s2 is the tail.
functions of this list:

1. insert(ele):just use s2.push_back(ele)
2. pop():if s1 is not empty,s1.pop();else pop each element from s2 and push them into s1, then s1.pop()
3. size():s1.size()+s2.size()
4. ...